# How does the compiler add a null-terminator when there is no more space?

Tags: c, string, memory-management, null

I know that this question had been asked a million times, but I still get confused. I intentionally make my string size equal to the char number in it:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char str[5] = "check";
    while((str[i] != '\0') && (i != 10)){ // (i != 10) aborts the func
        printf("str[i] = %c\n", *(str+i));
        printf("i = %d\n", i);
        i++;
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
str[i] = c
i = 0
str[i] = h
i = 1
str[i] = e
i = 2
str[i] = c
i = 3
str[i] = k
i = 4
```

Why does it still store null character at the end of it, despite there is no space allocated? Does it depend on the compiler, or do all of them work the same way?

Comment: This is undefined behavior.

Comment: Your code has only worked because, by chance, the memory allocated after your array is still empty and initialized to null. This may not always be the case. When defining arrays for string storage you MUST allow for an extra char at the end for a NULL to be stored.

Answer (score 3):

The standard library has

> A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.

With `char str[5] = "check";`, `str[]` is not a *string* as it lacks a *null character*.  `str[]` could be called an array of `char`.

---

After a few iterations, with `while((str[i] != '\0') && (i != 10)){`, code attempts `str[5]`, which is outside the `str[]`.  This is *undefined behavior* (**UB**) [@Vlad from Moscow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69461476/string-definition/69461738#comment122774176_69461476).  Anything may happened.

In OP's case, the UB was apparently `str[5]` is zero, ending the loop.  This may differ on a subsequent run.

Do not rely on this result.  It is UB.

---

> Why does it still store null character at the end of it, despite there is no space allocated?

The loop may have ended because a 0 was next in memory or other reasons. It is UB.

> Does it depend on the compiler,

There is no specified behavior based on the compilation.  There is no specification that the result is consistent.  It is UB.

> ... or do all of them work the same way?

There is no specification that they work the same way.  There is no specification that they work differently. It is UB.

Comment: thank you chux for your exhaustive answer

Answer (score 1):

You ask:

> Why does it still store null character at the end of it, despite there is no space allocated?

It doesn't. Please look at this modification of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    char a = 'x';
    char str[5] = "check";
    char b = 'x';
    while((str[i] != '\0') && (i != 10)){ // (i != 10) aborts the func
        printf("str[i] = %c\n", *(str+i));
        printf("i = %d\n", i);
        i++;
    }
}
```

In my case, it produced:

```
str[i] = c
i = 0
str[i] = h
i = 1
str[i] = e
i = 2
str[i] = c
i = 3
str[i] = k
i = 4
str[i] = x
i = 5
str[i] = x
i = 6
str[i] = 
i = 7
```

So it does **not** add a `\0` at the end. That next address *might* contain a `\0` but it would not have anything to do with `arr`. Instead, it has to do with what the compiler decides to put after it. And that may depend on a number of things. One of which is the size of `arr`, another is other variables in the same scope.

Don't make any assumptions. It's UB and the problem with this type of mistake is that it might just work.

Don't make any assumptions if it does work. Like you assumed a `\0` is added. It isn't.

Answer (score -2):

The way strings work in C is that on its end, there's always a special end character, `\0`(aka `null terminator`), which signals the end of the string.

Thing is, you haven't allocated enough space for the string to have the end character, so your loop just keeps going forward into your memory.

The reason your function is aborted at `i=10` is because as your program keeps going forward in the memory of your computer, it reaches a point where the memory you are trying to access is reserved for something more important than your program (say, the OS or files you have in your system), so the OS is like: **`OI LAD, where do you think you are going?`**, and kills your program, to protect the memory you are trying to access.

Comment: In your question, you wrote: `"it reaches a point where the memory you are trying to access is reserved for something more important than your program (say, the OS or files you have in your system)"` -- This statement is mostly incorrect. You seem to be confusing [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) with physical memory. On most modern operating systems, every process has its [own virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). (...)

Comment: (...) Also, it is much more likely that an access violation/segmentation fault will occur due to accessing unmapped memory/guard pages than accessing mapped memory that contains something important that is protected.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel  In 2021, most processors are embedded ones, 100 millions/year (even billions?).  C  very popular there.  Many systems (perhaps most) lack an OS where "On most modern operating systems ..." does not apply.

Comment: In the question the loop ends much earlier then 10